# Pass input value to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working away at mastering this Rails thing!

I have a topics (like a forum) which I am trying to associate to a chapter (a category). I am able to list the available chapters on the new page, but when I save I can't get it to save properly.

topics_controller.rb

```
def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
    @topic.user = current_user
    @topic.chapter = Chapter.find(params[:chapter_id])
```

Inside my form

`<%= f.collection_select :chapter_id, Chapter.all, :id, :name %>`

I would appreciate anyone's help! :)

Comment: Look at server logs. I suppose, params are like `topic: { chapter_id: 1}`. It means, you can access need parameter through `params[:topic][:chapter_id]`.

Comment: Nice! That got it to save. Now it's spitting out like #<Chapter:0x00007fa775a26268>. Any ideas on how to actually get the name? I'm using

`<%= link_to topic.chapter, topic.chapter %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind, I'll convert my comment to the answer, to not leave the question unanswered.

Look at server logs. I suppose, params are like `topic: { chapter_id: 1}`. It means, you can access needed parameter through `params[:topic][:chapter_id]`. But the better idea is to add `chapter_id` to permitted params (topic_params). In this case you can simplify create action a bit

```
# note - you can create a topic belonging to current_user in one line
def create
  @topic = current_user.topics.build(topic_params)
  if @topic.save
    redirect to topics_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(:title, :text, :all_other_parameters, :chapter_id)
end
```

You need to use chapter's name in the link. Supposing that it is `title` attribute:

```
<%= link_to topic.chapter.title, topic.chapter %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't quite get the topic_params part to work, but that's my homework now. I really appreciate your support!

Comment: @tommysvr You're welcome :) You can post a new question about topic_params and I'll try to help with it